# Android and MongoDB store and retrieve data

Tags: java, android, mongodb, rest, database

I have created several basic android apps but I am relatively new to connecting db with android. I have a simple page that asks the user to enter a name and password. When a button is clicked the data needs to be stored in an online DB.
I have created a Mongolab account and have installed mongodb in my computer.
I have referred many websites but none of them give a clear cut answer on how to achieve this action.Some say use node.js ,REST and all the other stuff. I dont even know what these mean. My need is to send these two string in the db. What should i do next?
Any sites that provide an answer will be helpful. If you need to see any part of my coding I will post it.

thanks in advance

Comment: For several reasons you need the stuff named in the websites that you read (Mainly security). You need a backend/server language in order to comunicate with the database. Backend retrieves data and returns it to the Android app .

Comment: mongodb is an online db so I assumed that it removed the need for a physical server.

Comment: Mongodb is like any other physical storage DB.  It is not "online" or "offline". It listens to connection request in some port and returns data to the queries.You made a Mongolab account which provides you a online easy install and acccess mongodb database. Mongodb also can be installed locally in your computer. You don´t need Mongolab for work with mongodb. I think that Mongolab stuff has confused you. what you ask for its the same than connect to a MySQL database directly from Android code without backend server request.

Comment: @cesarluis I get it now. No matter what I need to have physical server running. My need for server is to store username and password. I found a website called "parse" which I believe satisfies my need. If you a better solution or option please let me know.

Comment: Parse is a good option for externalize your backend. I did not name it before for avoid confusing you more. You can also make your own server with a language that you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb is like any other physical storage DB. It is not "online" or "offline". It listens to connection request in some port and returns data to the queries.

You made a Mongolab account which provides you a online easy install and acccess mongodb database. Mongodb also can be installed locally in your computer. You don´t need Mongolab for work with mongodb. I think that Mongolab stuff has confused you.

What you ask for its the same than connect to a MySQL database directly from Android code without backend server request.

I recommend you to make your own server + database with the technology that you want or use a service like [parse](https://www.parse.com/products/core). Parse easily set ups a backend for your app.